# Conditional intraclass correlation (ICC) from a linear mixed model as evidence for test-retest reliability?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, reliability, hierarchical-clustering, intraclass-correlation

In my experiment with two conditions (between-subjects design), participants completed a single-item scale three times: (1) before the experimental manipulation, (2) after the experimental manipulation, and (3) at the end of the study. I want to test the test-retest reliability of my single-item scale over three measurements.

The issue here is that the experimental manipulation is known to affect the response in the measure. I'm assuming that I need to control for any effect of the manipulation, so my guess is to use a linear mixed model (hierarchical linear model) with measurements nested within participants and include an experimental condition as a factor. This way, I can get an intraclass correlation (ICC) from this conditional model.

Would it be possible to interpret this conditional ICC as "a measure of test-retest reliability after controlling for the experimental effect"? Are there any existing studies using a similar approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this and interpret it as you think. I have read about such an interpretation in the second chapter of Sophia Rabe-Hesketh and Anders Skrondal's Multilevel and Longitudinal Modeling using Stata [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Multilevel_and_Longitudinal_Modeling_Usi.html?id=u2eZpwAACAAJ) (Volume 1).

A more detailed explanation follows. **Edit**: I also added a simulation to demonstrate what is going on. Hat tip to Ariel Muldoon for a helpful [blog post](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/04/23/simulate-simulate-part-2/) that aided me in creating this simulation.

In a random intercept model with no predictors,
$$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + u_{0j} + \epsilon_{ij}$$
we get two variances, one for $u_{0j}$, which is $\psi$, and one for $\epsilon_{ij}$, which is $\theta$.

From these we can express between-subject dependence or reliability ($\rho$) as:
$$\rho = \frac{\psi}{\psi+\theta}$$

In this equation, $\psi$ is the variance of subjects' true scores $\beta_0 + u_{0j}$ and $\theta$ is the measurement error variance, or squared standard error of measurement. $\rho$ becomes a test-retest reliability because of the repeated measurements.

In contrast to the Pearson correlation coefficient, $\rho$ is influenced by any linear transformations of measurements, which could include practice effects or experimentally-induced increases from time 1 to time 2. Thus, if you know of something in your data that induces linear changes, you must account for it in your mixed model.

In your case, you have a time-varying experimental manipulation (call it $x_1$). Including $x_1$ as a predictor in your random intercept model,

$$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 +u_{0j} + \epsilon_{ij}$$

will (likely) have an effect on both $\psi$ and $\theta$. In so doing, the resulting estimates of $\psi$ and $\theta$ are no longer influenced by $x_1$, and you have an estimate of test-retest reliability robust to experimental effects.

---

**Simulation**

```
set.seed(807)

npart=1000 # number of particpants
ntime=3    # numer of observations (timepoints) per participant
mu=2.5     # mean value on the Likert item
sdp=1      # standard deviation of participant random effect (variance==1)
sd=.7071   # standard deviation of within participant (residual; variance = .5)

participant = rep(rep(1:npart, each = nobs),ntime)  # creating 1000 participants w/ 3 repeats
participant = participant[order(participant)]
time = rep(rep(1:ntime, each=1),1000)    # creating a time variable

parteff = rnorm(npart, 0, sdp)     # drawing from normal for participant deviation
parteff = rep(parteff, each=ntime) # ensuring participant effect is same for three observations

timeeff = rnorm(npart*ntime, 0, sd) # drawing from normal for within-participant residual

dat=data.frame(participant, time, parteff, timeeff) # create data frame

dat$resp = with(dat, mu + parteff + timeeff ) # creating response for each individual

#Variance components model
library(lme4)

m1 <- lmer(resp ~ 1 + (1|participant), dat)
summary(m1) # estimates close to simulated values


Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: resp ~ 1 + (1 | participant)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 8523.8

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.13381 -0.57238  0.01722  0.57846  2.84918 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 1.0110   1.0055  
 Residual                0.5314   0.7289  
Number of obs: 3000, groups:  participant, 1000

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.54142    0.03447   73.73


#Add treatment variable x1 which turns on at time 3
dat$trtmt = rep(c(0,0,1),1000)
b1 = .4 #average amount by which particpant's score increases b/c of treatment
x1 = runif(npart, .05, 1.5)


library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(resp2=case_when
                      (time==3 ~ (mu+b1*x1+parteff+timeeff),
                        TRUE ~ resp))
glimpse(dat)

#run m1 without covariate for trtmt
m2 <- lmer(resp2 ~ 1 + (1|participant), dat)
summary(m2)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: resp2 ~ 1 + (1 | participant)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 8659.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.72238 -0.56861  0.01894  0.57177  3.10610 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 1.0070   1.0035  
 Residual                0.5669   0.7529  
Number of obs: 3000, groups:  participant, 1000

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.64169    0.03458   76.39


#add trtmt as a fixed effect predictor
m3 <- lmer(resp2 ~ 1 + trtmt + (1|participant), dat)
summary(m3)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: resp2 ~ 1 + trtmt + (1 | participant)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 8546.7

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.06878 -0.57650  0.02712  0.57887  2.89709 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 participant (Intercept) 1.0178   1.0088  
 Residual                0.5346   0.7311  
Number of obs: 3000, groups:  participant, 1000

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2.53746    0.03585   70.78
trtmt        0.31270    0.02832   11.04

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr)
trtmt -0.263

> texreg::screenreg(c(m1, m2, m3))

======================================================================
                              Model 1       Model 2       Model 3     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)                       2.54 ***      2.64 ***      2.54 ***
                                 (0.03)        (0.03)        (0.04)   
trtmt                                                         0.31 ***
                                                             (0.03)   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                            8529.83       8665.86       8554.72    
BIC                            8547.85       8683.88       8578.75    
Log Likelihood                -4261.92      -4329.93      -4273.36    
Num. obs.                      3000          3000          3000       
Num. groups: participant       1000          1000          1000       
Var: participant (Intercept)      1.01          1.01          1.02    
Var: Residual                     0.53          0.57          0.53    
======================================================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Answer (score 2):

This post really helped me and I wanted to thank you.
In case other users ran to the same issue I had - I am adding a slight change to the simulation above. The only thing here is that this shows that Pearson corr for two times measurements is exactly the same as $\rho$. Nothing special - only nice to see the numbers match :) Also, ever so slight correction in the participant vector to make this work.

Cheers

Nitzan

````
set.seed(807)

npart=1000 # number of particpants
ntime=2   # numer of observations (timepoints) per participant
mu=2.5     # mean value on the Likert item
sdp=1      # standard deviation of participant random effect (variance==1)
sd=.7071   # standard deviation of within participant (residual; variance = .5)

participant = rep(rep(1:npart, each = nobs),ntime)  # creating 1000 participants w/ 3 repeats
participant = participant[order(participant)]
time        = rep(rep(1:ntime, each=1),1000)        # creating a time variable

parteff = rnorm(npart, 0, sdp)     # drawing from normal for participant deviation
parteff = rep(parteff, each=ntime) # ensuring participant effect is same for three observations

timeeff = rnorm(npart*ntime, 0, sd) # drawing from normal for within-participant residual

dat=data.frame(participant, time, parteff, timeeff) # create data frame

dat$resp = with(dat, mu + parteff + timeeff ) # creating response for each individual

#Variance components model
library(lme4)

m1 <- lmer(resp ~ 1 + (1|participant), dat)
summary(m1) # estimates close to simulated values

#calculate pearson corr
library(reshape2)
df.wide   <-dcast(dat,participant~time,mean,value.var='resp')[,-1]
cor(df.wide)

#get the same from the HLM fit
print(VarCorr(m1))
.95478^2/(.95478^2+0.74685^2)
 ```
````

Comment: Thank you, @nitzan shahar!  (+1) A good catch on the code for creating participants. I updated in the code in my post accordingly. And yes, nice to see the confirmation from the Pearson correlation once you reshape the data to wide.